# iOS App Store App listed as ‘supports Siri’?

Tags: ios

For any given app in the App Store, what does it mean if the App is listed as ‘supports Siri’?

The BBC sounds App doesn’t offer any features via the shortcuts App? What else does Siri offer in support of an App beyond that?

Commands like “hey Siri, open App X” are not specific ‘Siri enabled features’ on a per app basis in my opinion. That’s just system wide functionality right?

Answer (score 1):

Apple calls these app intents now and has for some time conflated Siri with Spotlight search so when apps “support Siri” it means a lot more than just “hey Siri, automate this” in practice since this started with iOS 10.

- allowing the app to register for things like focus suggestions
- Allowing the app to register for things like Siri suggestions
- Automation
- Voiceover and other accessibility benefits accrue with this

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10032

For developers, this means a lot of benefits of the API and features that apple provides for the platform. For consumers of the apps, it makes the interaction of the apps within the ecosystem more rich and enables some cool features and integrations.